# Rails: best way to log GET requests in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a complete Ruby and Rails newbie, so please excuse the question. Given a spec making a GET request: `get :filter_by_foo, params: {Foo: Bar}`

What is the best way to output the generated GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be two variables available to you in the test case called `request` and `response`. if i understand your question correctly, you'd want to `p request` inside your test case

```
describe SomeController do
  before(:each) { get :filter_by_foo, params: {Foo: Bar} }

  it 'should have some variables available' do
    p request
    # p response
    expect(true).to be(true)
  end
end
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! :)

Comment: In fact, what if I just wanted the raw request data? For example, the URL?

Comment: then start debugging with the request object. if you `p request.inspect` tou should see all of the data on the request object. one of those methods surely includes the url. if you want to further debug, i'd use debugger gems like the pry debugger gem so you can `binding.pry` inside the test case and use a console with the request object